# Java Collection compare generic class that extends interface that extends comparable

Tags: java, generics

I have this interface

```
public interface IDataPoint<T> extends Comparable<T>  {
    public T getValue();
}
```

and this implementation...

```
public class IntegerDataPoint implements IDataPoint<Integer> {

    // ... some code omitted for this example

    public int compareTo(Integer another) {
         // ... some code
    }
}
```

and another class...

```
public class HeatMap<X extends IDataPoint<?> {
    private List<X> xPoints;
}
```

Now I would like to use Collections.max (and similar) on the `xPoints` list, but that does not work, probably because I got my generics all messed up.

Any suggestions how this could be solved (without a `Comparator`)?

```
Collections.max(xPoints);
```

gives me this error:

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method max(Collection<? extends T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<X>). The inferred type X is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'does not work'? Your compareTo is not called?

Comment: Please define the "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `Collections.max(Collection<? extends T>)` wants the T's to be comparable to **themselves** not some other type.

In your case `IntegerDataPoint` is comparable to **`Integer`**, but not **`IntegerDataPoint`**

You cannot easily fix this because `IntegerDataPoint` is not allowed to implement `Comparable<Integer>` and `Comparable<IntegerDataPoint>` at the same time.